# django templates question

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I get the value of form.field in template. I mean not the html input element of the field but the value inside the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the bound data (in 1.2.3)

```
{{ form.field.data }}
```

In the development version, it's `{{ form.field.value }}` which automatically pulls initial data OR bound data whereas it's an explicit call in the current release:

`form.field.field.initial` or `form.field.data`

---

Update: the admin forms work differently. First of all, the `BoundField` is `{{ adminfield.field }}` and not `{{ adminfield }}` in your comment, but we have bigger problems.

On the change form, the form is **not bound** so data can only be pulled from the initial dictionary passed into the form constructor. It's not accessible via the django template syntax.

Here's the relevant lines in `BoundField`:

```
    if not self.form.is_bound:
        data = self.form.initial.get(self.name, self.field.initial)
        # you can't do this kind of lookup from the template.
```

The only way to access this type of info from the template without making a template tag (which you should!) is to loop through each key/value in the initial dictionary and comparing to the current fields name.

```
  {% for line in fieldset %}
    {% for adminfield in line %}
            {% for k, v in adminfield.field.form.initial.items %}
                {% if k == adminfield.field.name %}
                    {{ k }}:{{ v }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you post your form code and template then? For a form constructed `form(request.POST)`, the bound data will be available in `form.field.data` in the current release.

Comment: I am trying to get the name of my object in a change_form.html. The code is:

Comment: {% for fieldset in adminform %}
    {% for line in fieldset %}
        {% for field in line %}
            {{ field.data }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: If you're trying to modify admin forms, that changes everything as its' not standard usage of forms. I"ll post what I found after digging around.